# Can't convert int to bool c# form

Tags: c#

I'm creating a simple guessing game that has a hard-coded number. When the user enters a number into the text box and clicks the button, if the number is too low then the background will turn blue and say "Too low." If the number is too high the background will turn red and say "Too high." Finally, if guessed correctly then the background will turn green and say "That's correct!"

I feel the answer is right in front of me, but I can't seem to figure out to get it right. I'm pretty sure I have to do some sort of conversion on line 43 and 46 right?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace A12_02
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Hardcoded number.
            int SecNum = 75;

            //Users input.
            int Guess = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

            //Users input was too low.
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Guess) < SecNum)
                this.BackColor = Color.Blue;

            if (Convert.ToInt32(Guess) < SecNum)
                OutputText.Text = "Too low.";

            //Users input was too high.
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Guess) > SecNum)
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;

            if (Convert.ToInt32(Guess) > SecNum)
                OutputText.Text = "Too high.";

            //Users input was correct.
            if (Guess = SecNum)
                this.BackColor = Color.Green;

            if (Guess = SecNum)
                OutputText.Text = "That's correct!";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (Guess == SecNum)
         this.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

You are assigning value by mistake I guess, it should be like above.

Comment: I knew it was something easy. That was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a single `=` is an assignment. You need to use `==` when comparing for equality. Also, you don't need to repeat check the same conditions. Your code can be condensed somehwat:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Hardcoded number.
    int SecNum = 75;

    //Users input.
    int Guess = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    if (Guess < SecNum) {
        this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        OutputText.Text = "Too low.";
    } else if (Guess > SecNum) {
        this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        OutputText.Text = "Too high.";
    } else {
        this.BackColor = Color.Green;
        OutputText.Text = "That's correct!";
    }
}
```